# printf() not printing correct computation

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

C++ Programmer here , need a quick solution for problem below.

I need to carry out following subtraction where input is taken from a file and desired numbers are stored in variables. However printf() is showing 0 as the value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{   system("clear");
    system("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal");
    system("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree ");
    int a=system("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | grep -Eo [0-9]+");
    int b=system("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | grep -Eo [0-9]+");
    int c=a-b;
    printf("%d \n",c);
}
```

Output is as following:

```
MemTotal:        3913212 kB
MemFree:         1769672 kB
3913212
1769388
0
```

Moreover is there a way to supress output from 7th and 8th line in code as i just need them to store in variables.

Edit : Fixed long int.

Thanks

Comment: 1) type of return value of `system` is `int`. 2) return value of grep is not display value.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ahh yes , 1 fixed and how to go about 2nd? how should i store grep(display value) in a var?

Comment: Receive from file stream by pipe(use `popen`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c)

Comment: @indiv , yeah possibly if i could do it within c.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY a simple snippet would help :)

Comment: Just wanted to suggest perhaps using [sysinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysinfo) to get this information instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample ( tested ) of popen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    system("clear");
    system(" grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo");
    system(" grep MemFree /proc/meminfo");

    int totalMem=0 , freeMem=0;
    FILE *fp =  popen("grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | grep -Eo [0-9]+", "r");
    FILE *fp1 = popen("grep MemFree /proc/meminfo | grep -Eo [0-9]+", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &totalMem);
    fscanf(fp1, "%d", &freeMem);
    printf("%d \n",totalMem-freeMem);
    pclose(fp);
    pclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: really helped , with not so much examples for usage of popen() around.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/meminfo` is a special file, mapped from the kernel into userspace. the easiest way to access such information is .. to not parse that file but use a systemcall instead:

```
// build: cc -o mratio-si mratio-si.c
// usage: ./mratio-si
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct sysinfo si;
    if (sysinfo(&si) == 0) {
        printf("%d/%d (%.2f)\n", si.freeram, si.totalram,.
            (float)si.freeram/(float)si.totalram);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

or, since we have a real programming-language at hand, parse `/proc/meminfo` ourselves:

```
// build: cc -o mratio-parse mratio-parse.c
// usage: ./mratio-parse < /proc/meminfo
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const char MEMTOTAL[] = "MemTotal:"; const char MEMFREE[] = "MemFree:";
    long val, memfree = 0, memtotal = 0;
    char buf[256]; void* ignore; int ok = 0;

    for (; ok != EOF && !(memfree > 0 && memtotal > 0); ){
        ok = fscanf(stdin, "%255s %d %*s\n", buf, &val, ignore);
        if (ok == 0) { return 1; }
        if (strncmp(buf, MEMTOTAL, sizeof(MEMTOTAL)-1) == 0) {
            memtotal = val;
        } else if (strncmp(buf, MEMFREE, sizeof(MEMFREE)-1) == 0) {
            memfree = val;
        }
    }

    if (memfree == 0 || memtotal == 0) {
        perror("parse error, did not find 'MemFree' or 'MemTotal'\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d/%d (%.2f)\n", memfree, memtotal, (float)memfree/(float)memtotal);
    return 0;
}
```

in any case, using `popen()` is obviously possible as well but has some kind of overhead (and consistency problems because there is some time between the first `grep` and the last invocation of it, invoking `grep` itself changes `/proc/meminfo` because it eats, well, memory).